# RavenDB 2.5 LoadByUniqueConstraint failing to Load

Tags: c#, ravendb

Here's a [reproduction](https://github.com/clinington/RavenBulkTest)

Using build 2.5.2910

So we store a member in the database the normal way:

```
await session.StoreAsync(member)
```

I can then sign in, as that member, when

```
await session.LoadByUniqueConstraintAsync<Member>(m => m.Email, email)
```

I then do a batch update of email addresses (the batch only contains that one email address)

```
for (var batch = 0; (records = allRecords.Skip(batch * BatchSize).Take(BatchSize).ToList()).Any(); batch++) 
{
    using(var querySession = this.documentStore.OpenSession()) 
    {
        var existingMembers = session.Query<Member, Member_ByEmail> ().Where(m => m.Email.In(records.Select(r => r.OldEmailAddress))).ToDictionary(m => m.Email, m => m);

        using(var bulkInsertOperation = this.documentStore.BulkInsert(this.systemConfiguration.DatabaseName, new BulkInsertOptions { CheckForUpdates = true })) 
        {
            foreach(var member in records) 
            {
                var existingMemberKey = member.OldEmailAddress;
                var existingMemberRecord = existingMembers[existingMemberKey];
                existingMemberRecord.Email = member.EmailAddress;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try and log in again with the new email address, this line:

```
await session.LoadByUniqueConstraintAsync<Member>(m => m.Email, email)
```

Returns null....

I've checked the new email being used is the same one in the database. The database shows the new one. I've used the database interface and queried the index for the new email and that works.

I've set the database to use wait for non stale results and also:

```
store.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.AlwaysWaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite;
```

None of these options have worked.

I'm wondering if there is something special I have to do with bulk insert operation in order to get the .NET client to read the indexes for this new email.

I've drilled into the session variable at runtime and found that there is a known missing ids field with this value:

```
"UniqueConstraints/members/email/Ym1hcmxleTFAbmV3b3JiaXQuY28udWs="
```

Comment: Hey @CallumLinington, I am wondering if you ever found a solution to this. I am now working on the same project and experiencing this issue

Comment: I've now found the solution, will add it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Raven plugin `Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints.dll` and add it to the `\Plugins\` directory in your Raven installation folder (in my case, `D:\RavenDB\Plugins`)

You will need to re-insert the records after doing this (I deleted the database and re-seeded).